# How can I make align all the textboxes align in same vertical position in wpf?

Tags: wpf

Hi i created lable's and text boxs in wpf but text boxes are started different position How can I make align all the textboxes align in same vertical position?

```
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left"
   Style="{DynamicResource EditorHLabelNoIdentStyle}" Content="{x:Static r:Resources.LABEL_POSITION}"/> 
   <TextBox ToolTip="{x:Static r:Resources.LABEL_POSITION_TIP}"
  Style="{DynamicResource EditorTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding XPath=nameofthedataset, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </DockPanel>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left"
   Style="{DynamicResource EditorHLabelNoIdentStyle}" Content="{x:Static r:Resources.LABEL_POSITION}"/> 
   <TextBox ToolTip="{x:Static r:Resources.LABEL_POSITION_TIP}"
  Style="{DynamicResource EditorTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding XPath=keywords, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
   </DockPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: Might I suggest a `Grid` with two columns. `Label` in the first and `TextBox` in the second with the second column being minimum, adjustable size e.g. `100*`.

Comment: And all Labels might be (simpler) TextBlocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Grid` with two `ColumnDefinitions` and a `RowDefinition` for each row and then set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties 
of each element to specify its position in the `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{DynamicResource EditorHLabelNoIdentStyle}" Content="{x:Static r:Resources.LABEL_POSITION}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" ToolTip="{x:Static r:Resources.LABEL_POSITION_TIP}" Style="{DynamicResource EditorTextBoxStyle}" 
                     Text="{Binding XPath=nameofthedataset, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{DynamicResource EditorHLabelNoIdentStyle}" Content="{x:Static r:Resources.LABEL_POSITION}"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ToolTip="{x:Static r:Resources.LABEL_POSITION_TIP}"
                     Style="{DynamicResource EditorTextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding XPath=keywords, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

With a number of rows, setting labels or texblocks and textboxes to row and column quickly gets a bit tedious.
You could instead use standard template to line things up in a stackpanel.

A headeredcontentcontrol has a template with a stackpanel to put a header above it's content. This xaml re-templates to use a grid with two columns. The size of the first is shared across the scope of it's containing stackpanel.
You can also avoid repeating all your standard styling and whatnot by applying it in the template.

My markup uses simplified example controls for clarity.

Your textboxes ( or whichever control you wanted to label ) complete with binding, tooltip etc go in the content of a headeredcontentcontrol. The label gets it's value from the header property.

The shared size scope and auto size on the column means all the instances end up with the maximum necessary width a label in that stackpanel requests. So the right column of controls (textboxes) lines up.

```
    <StackPanel Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="L" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                       Margin="2,2,4,2"
                                           />
                                <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="Label 1:">
            <TextBox Text="Some textbox"/>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
        <HeaderedContentControl Header="A much longer label:">
            <TextBox Text="A second textbox"/>
        </HeaderedContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
```